# how to output only when command finish

Tags: linux, bash, concurrency, stdout

I'm running multiple commands using `&`:

```
curl "url1" --output /dev/null 2>> out &
curl "url1" --output /dev/null 2>> out &
wait
```

This doesn't work well because the output lines are interleaved. I want each `curl` to hold its output, until it's done. How to do that?

I understand I can use temp files, concat together and delete afterwards. Are there better ways?

```
curl "url1" --output /dev/null 2>> out1 &
curl "url1" --output /dev/null 2>> out2 &
wait
```

Comment: Seems like there are some details you missed to explain: 1. You want to buffer stderr, not stdout. 2. Stderr output should be written to the file `out`. I'll edit my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could execute each `curl` inside a subshell:

```
echo "$(curl "url1" 2>&1 >/dev/null)" >> out &
echo "$(curl "url2" 2>&1 >/dev/null)" >> out &
wait
```

`2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout.
And yes, you can have nested `""` with the subshell command `$()` :)

**Downside:** This may not preserve the order of outputs. In case the second `curl` completes first, it outputs first.

In order to keep the outputs ordered, you could use `cat` and `<()`. Bash's *process substitution* `<(COMMAND)` creates a temporary file (actually, it's a FIFO) from the output of `COMMAND`, but you don't have to care about name, creation, and deletion of that temporary file.

```
cat \
<(curl "url1" 2>&1 >/dev/null) \
<(curl "url2" 2>&1 >/dev/null) \
> out
```

The `\` escapes the line breaks. Without the `\` everything has to be written in one line.

Comment: Hi, the downside is acceptable in my use case... thanks!